# Why isn't GLProfiler returning values in my example?

Tags: java, libgdx

In my Game constructor I add this:

```
GLProfiler.enable();
```

And at the end of all my draw calls in my render method I add this:

```
Gdx.app.log("drawCalls", String.valueOf(GLProfiler.drawCalls));
Gdx.app.log("calls", String.valueOf(GLProfiler.calls));
Gdx.app.log("textureBindings", String.valueOf(GLProfiler.textureBindings));
Gdx.app.log("shaderSwitches ", String.valueOf(GLProfiler.shaderSwitches));
Gdx.app.log("vertexCount ", String.valueOf(GLProfiler.vertexCount.value ));

GLProfiler.reset();
```

But all values in the Android Monitor are returning zeros. I do not have any instances of Gdx.graphics.getGL20() or Gdx.graphics.getGL30() in my code. I clear each frame like this:

```
Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl20.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You get zeros on desktop too?

Comment: No, desktop build reports actual numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this myself. The problem was that I was enabling the profiler in the main game constructor. Moving the GLProfiler.enable() call to the last line of the create() method fixed it.